# Jenkins and Jelly (ext-email plugin)

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins, email-ext

I am using a jelly script with ext-email plugin. If I would like to add a picture myself how do I do that in a jelly script. I have tried alot of diffrent ways but still it is the wrong search way.

```
<IMG SRC="${JENKINS_HOME}email-templates/jenkins-logo/jenkins-logo/32x32/logotitle.jpg"/>
<IMG SRC="${rooturl}email-templates/jenkins-logo/jenkins-logo/32x32/logotitle.png"/>
<IMG SRC="${rooturl}Jenkins/email-templates/jenkins-logo/jenkins-logo/32x32/logotitle.gif"/>
<IMG SRC="C:/Jenkins/email-templates/jenkins-logo/jenkins-logo/32x32/logotitle.gif"/>
```

Please advise me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use userContent directory to use any external resources.

For your problem:

**1.** You should put "myself.png" to `$JENKINS_HOME/userContent` directory

**2.** In jelly script you may use `<IMG SRC="${rooturl}/userContent/myself.png"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also include your screenshot as attachment. In the advance options of "Editable email notifications" plugin there is such a place:

[image]

Specify the name of your image which should be stored in a workspace.